# Difference between document.hidden vs document.hasFocus()

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

Please explain the difference between `document.hidden` , the HTML5 Page Visibility API and `document.hasFocus()`. I am doing a project which pops `HTML5 Desktop Notification` when the tab is not focused. I am kind of confused which one to use.

Comment: Try using `document.hidden` in IE9 and you'll understand. Try using `hasFocus` in Opera and you'll understand.

Comment: Does it means both serves same purpose

Comment: "use it and you'll understand".  Imagine if all documentation was like this.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The [`hidden` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/#dom-document-hidden) is defined like this:

> On getting, the [`hidden`](http://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/#dom-document-hidden) attribute MUST return true if the
>   [Document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#document) contained by the [top level browsing context](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#top-level-browsing-context) (root
>   window in the browser's viewport) is not visible at all. The attribute
>   MUST return false if the [Document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#document) contained by the [top level
>   browsing context](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#top-level-browsing-context) is at least partially visible on at least one
>   screen.
>
> If the [defaultView](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#dom-document-defaultview) of the [Document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#document) is null, on getting, the
>   [`hidden`](http://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/#dom-document-hidden) attribute MUST return true.

The [`hasFocus` method](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#dom-document-hasfocus) is defined like this

> The `hasFocus()` method on [`Document`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#document) objects must return true if
>   the [`Document`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#document)'s [browsing context](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#browsing-context) is focused, and all its
>   [ancestor browsing contexts](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#ancestor-browsing-context) are also focused, and the [top-level
>   browsing context](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#top-level-browsing-context) has the *system focus*. If the [`Document`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#document)
>   has no [browsing context](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#browsing-context) or if its [browsing context](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#browsing-context) has no
>   [top-level browsing context](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#top-level-browsing-context), then the method will always return
>   false.

For example, if you open a page in a foreground tab, and then open another window, the tab will (or may) still be partially visible, so `hidden` returns false. However, the new window has focus, so `hasFocus()` returns false for the tab.

If you run the following snippet, the document inside the iframe will be visible but won't have focus (this stackoverflow page is focused instead):

```js
document.body.innerHTML = 
  '<p>hidden: ' + document.hidden + '</p>' +
  '<p>hasFocus: ' + document.hasFocus() + '</p>';
```

But in this other one, since you click the button inside the iframe, it is both visible and focused:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].onclick = function() {
  document.body.innerHTML = 
    '<p>hidden: ' + document.hidden + '</p>' +
    '<p>hasFocus: ' + document.hasFocus() + '</p>';
};
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Click me!" />
```

Answer (score 7):

TLDR:

`document.hidden`: returns `true` if tab is open and is not at all visible. Opening another chrome window and covering the open tab would make it return true

`document.hasFocus()`: returns `true` if the tab is the open tab and no other window has focus. Opening a chrome window would make that window have focus, so the open tab in the background, although visible, would return `false`

Comment: Why do you say "web-app is running"? isn't the question on Javascript/dom?
Honestly, this answer is confusing. Can you please rephrase?