# Vue - refresh state on clicking back button in the browser

Tags: vue.js, browser, axios, vue-component, vue-router

I am developing a login page, which lists different provider options. If you click on a provider, it will redirect to the sign-in page of the respective provider. This login component has a bool variable "pageRedirect". If pageRedirect is true, the component displays "Redirecting...", otherwise it displays the list of providers.

```
<template>
    <div v-if="pageRedirect">
      <h1>Redirecting...</h1>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
     <!-- list of providers -->
    </div>
</template>
```

If you click on a provider, the pageRedirect value will be set true and there is an axios call that goes to backend. The redirect happens in the go backend using http.Redirect(). In the mean time, the method that sets the pageRedirect completes. So when I hit the back button in the browser from the redirected page, it returns to the login page which displays "Redirecting..." and does not display the list of providers. This is because the pageRedirect value is still true.

```
axios
   .post("/redirectUrl", body, nil)
     .then(function (response)
      {
              this.pageRedirect = true;
              window.location.href = response.headers.location;
              // if I add this.pageRedirect=false here, it shows "Redirecting...", but doesnt
              // doesnt redirect itself
      }).
     .catch(function (response) {
            //display error
     });
```

If I try to set the pageRedirect to false in the same method, it is not redirecting itself, it remains on the same page. So I need some solution like vue-watchers or something to set this pageRedirect value to false on hitting back button in the browser from the redirected page.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I think you have to use [Watchers](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html) in conjunction with [document.hidden /document.hasfocus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29331979/difference-between-document-hidden-vs-document-hasfocus)

Comment: if you have vue-router you should be using `router.push` or `router.replace` functions instead of `window.location`.  Regardless, nothing really explains why setting `this.pageRedirect` false prevents the redirect.  the line `window.location.href` should execute regardless of what `this.pageRedirect` is doing... and normally when a component is navigated away from it's destroyed, so if you go back to it it's recreated with all initial values, so how `pageRedirect` stays `true` is a real mystery. I'd be interested in seeing more code for the two pages in question if you can provide it.

Comment: Sorry @yoduh, I misinformed. When this.pageRedirect=false, the redirect is happening fine, but the text "Redirecting..." is not showing up. But displaying "Redirecting..." is a requirement. 
And the component navigation, you are right. It should be recreated with initial values. But it isn't.

Comment: @yoduh If I use this.$router.push(redirectUrl). For instance, the redirectUrl is "https://www.redirectUrl.com/connect/". Then the router is taking me to "localhost:<port>/https://www.redirectUrl.com/connect/". Only if use window.location.href, it is taking me to "https://www.redirectUrl.com/connect/"

Comment: Can you share more information about the `vue component` file? Only with the post method is hard to identify the issue. `vue-router` is meant for internal redirections. If you want to redirect outside your platform, one way to go is with `window.location.href` you are currently using. 

As soon as you click back button from the outsider url and land back into your platform, all the states of your component should be reseted back to the initial state. Unless you are somehow persisting the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by using document visibilityState.

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => {
       this.pageRedirect=false;
});
```

Thanks @yoduh and @Jose Fernández for your valuable comments